# Is there any other way to solve this roots of unity question without using de Moivre's Theorem?

Tags: integration

Let $x$ and $y$ $\in \mathbb{R}$, and $\omega$, where $\omega \neq 1$, be one of the complex solutions of the equation, $z^3 = 1$. Evaluate:

(a) $1+\omega+\omega^2$

(b) $(\omega x+\omega^2y)(\omega^2x+\omega y)$

Comment: But why the 'integration' tag?

Comment: Evaluated. Now what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\omega\Big(1+\omega+\omega^2\Big) = \omega + \omega^2 + \omega^3 = \omega + \omega^2 + 1
$$
Thus we have
$$
\omega\Big(1+\omega+\omega^2\Big) = 1+\omega+\omega^2.
$$
$$
\omega\Big(1+\omega+\omega^2\Big) - \Big(1+\omega+\omega^2\Big) = 0
$$
$$
(\omega-1)\Big(1+\omega+\omega^2\Big) = 0.
$$
Dividing both sides by $\omega-1$, we get
$$
1+\omega+\omega^2 = 0.
$$

In part (b), first multiply it out, getting an sum in which each term is a real number times a power of $\omega$.  Whereever you see $\omega$ raised to a higher power than $2$, reduce it, thus:

Reduce $\omega^3$ to $1$.

Reduce $\omega^4$ to $\omega^3\cdot\omega = 1\cdot\omega = \omega$.

Reduce $\omega^5$ to $\omega^3\cdot\omega^2 = 1\cdot\omega^2 = \omega^2$.

Reduce $\omega^6$ to $\omega^3\cdot\omega^3 = 1\cdot1 = 1$.

And so on.

Comment: then you will get $x+y+\omega^2y+\omega x y$. Is this the answer?

Comment: The answer is $x^2 + y^2 - xy$

Comment: Nvm I'm kinda stupid, mistyped the question. Still stuck though, but I corrected it. Pardon me because I'm kinda new to this site.

Comment: then you will get $x^2\omega^3 + xy\omega^2+xy\omega^4+y^2\omega^3=x^2+y^2+xy\omega^2+xy\omega$

Comment: Realised that $\omega^2+\omega$ is -1 due to part (a)

Answer (score 1):

$z^3-1=0$ is $(z-1)(z^2+z+1)=0$ if $\omega$ is the complex root then $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$

Comment: I like this best.

Answer (score 0):

(a) We can write $\omega^2+\omega+1$ as $\frac{\omega^3-1}{\omega-1}$, since $\omega$ is complex and therefore $\not= 1$.  In that case, since $\omega$ is a complex cube root of $1$, $\omega^3 = 1$, and the fraction and the original expression are identically $0$.

(b) [ETA: Edited to reflect correction in OP's question.]  We can write

\begin{align}
(\omega x+\omega^2y)(\omega^2x+\omega y)
    & = \omega^3x^2+\omega^2xy+\omega^4xy+\omega^3y \\
    & = x+\omega^2xy+\omega xy+y \\
    & = x+(\omega^2+\omega)xy+y
\end{align}

Now, given the answer to part (a), you can simplify this last expression to remove the dependency on $\omega$.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I changed it though.

Comment: @Jeremy: OK, I changed my answer.